# How do you save an Animated GIF file using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, cs5, gif

I am making a `.gif` file in Photoshop CS5. While saving this animation, I used the steps = `File > Save for web & devices > Preset= GIF 128 Dithered > GIF > Save`.  After saving the `.gif` file it does not show the animation.
So what is wrong with the procedure?

Comment: Did you set the animation options on the right side of the Save for Web window?

Comment: Are you saying about animation looping option.?

Comment: yes I have choose forever option for looping.

Comment: Have you tried opening your animation in a browser to test?

Answer (score 27):

- The file **must** have a Timeline or Frame sequence. (`Window > Timeline`)
- You need to set the animation options in the Save for Web dialog:

[image: animation options]

In addition, it is possible to have a quick animation and not see it initially due to speed and duration if the Save For Web options are set to "once". You may need to reload a page/image to see the animation.

Also, some browsers have an option to disable gif animation. If you've done all the above, verify it's not a browser setting preventing the animation from being visible.

Comment: Note: in newer Photoshop CC, you still need to use the old Save for Web command to export GIFs with animation. It's under _File > Export > Save for Web (Legacy)..._

Comment: @peterflynn is there a way to export to gif with animation using the new export settings? (it's not important, I'm just curious)

Answer (score 0):

Try duplicating those presets in a 'Custom' preset. Try changing the path that the file is saved to also to see if that works.