# Flash won't export fully transparent gifs?

Tags: transparency, gif, adobe-flash

I've been using Flash for a while and never had any issues before, but suddenly when I export a transparent gif not all of it will be transparent after publishing.

For example, if I have a gif of a dog I drew wagging its tail and I want it to export with a transparent background, the rest of the dog will show up transparent but as the tail moves a big white box appears around it.

I'm importing the images from Photoshop layers and everything else works fine, it just seems to pick random elements from the animation and not publish them.

I publish them with these settings:

[image: settings of PS]

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Flash's gif rendering engine is really poor. I've never been able to reproduce clean results no matter how much time I've spent fidgeting with the publishing settings. You might try exporting a .png sequence then putting it together in Photoshop and exporting as a gif.

After Effects does a much better job of rendering animated gifs.

Comment: I've tried importing it into Photoshop CS6 but for some reason can't export as a gif.  I mean unless I'm just doing it wrong.

Comment: Are you using the timeline to create an animation? Here's another post from this site where @scott explains [how to make an animated GIF in Photoshop](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19289/how-do-you-save-an-animated-gif-file-using-photoshop)